# Unable to install ibus avro in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (32 bit)

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, ibus

I used these instructions given here:
(http://linux.omicronlab.com/ubuntu_14.04.html) to install ibus Avro in my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (32 bit) but first command was not working to go for next. Can anyone help me to solve this case?

Comment: Could you add which commands did you use from the link and also errors that you got running the commands? They can help to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to install iBus-avro in your system:

Install iBus first.

```
sudo apt-get install libibus-1.0-5 ibus gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gir1.2-glib-2.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-gtk-2.0
```

Now download and install ibus-avro-trusty package from the developer Sarim Khan's OpenSuse repository.

```
wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_14.04/i386/ibus-avro-trusty_1.2_i386.deb -P /tmp/avro/
sudo apt install gjs libgjs0e libmozjs-24-0v5
sudo dpkg -i /tmp/avro/*.deb
```

Now open Settings > Region and Language > Search and add 'Bengali (Avro phonetic)'.

Comment: Thank u for answer. i run this two command  in terminal, it's works normally, after finish from dash i do not find ibus, it is also not viewed on top bar . i can not add Bengali(avro phonetic)